# how to email / notify admin when users log in to the linux server

Tags: linux

I'm looking for an easy way to configure my server, so that whenever a user logs into it, I get an email about it.

Any pointers around how to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

Somebody has already built a [notification module for PAM](http://www.svitanok.si/projects/pam_notify/). I would look into downloading that and entering an appropriate configuration line in your related `/etc/pam.d/` files.

If your users are restricted in what shells they select and they all process /etc/profile (bash does), you can write a script into that.

Answer (score -1):

If your default shell is bash, you can add a sendmail entry to every .bashrc file to notify yourself of user logins.

I am sorry if it does not work that way. I am noob and trying to help you here.

Comment: Things that may make that an issue: `chsh` and the ability of a user to edit their own .bashrc.